# How to get this bootstrap drop-down to appear on top of fixed page header?

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

Does anyone know what amendment would need to be made to the code at http://jsfiddle.net/ufkkdbja/ so that when the hamburger is clicked the whole menu appears (and doesn't get truncated by the fixed page header?

```
  <header class="outer page-header">
<div class="dvTableTop">
    <div class="dvTableTopRow">
        <div class="dvTableTopRowCellLeft">
            <div class="container menu1">
                <!-- Dropdown left -->
                <div class="dropdown dropdownMenu">                        
                    <button class="c-hamburger c-hamburger--htla" id='btSwitch' type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span>toggle menu</span>
</button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">Home</asp:LinkButton></li>
```

TIA
Mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've added .page-header `overflow: hidden`, remove it or make it `visible` instead.

```
.page-header {
   overflow: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your css, for '.page-header', remove the 'overflow: hidden;'